# Is personal productivity a relevant topic for this site?

Tags: support

I have a question regarding personal productivity and I cannot figure out in which Stackexchange site I should post it. Initially I thought that should be Lifehacks, but there's no "productivity" tag there and just by browsing the site, I do not see any questions of that kind posted.

On the other hand, productivity is being discussed here, on "The Workplace". But since it is a question with personal productivity context (although relevant for the workplace, as well), I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask?

Comment: It's not relevant unless you are talking about productivity at work.

Comment: you can post question here as a "sandbox". You will not receive answers, but will get guidance on writing and/or finding better place for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask?

As long as you phrase it in an on-topic way it's ok.

We currently have a [productivity](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/productivity) tag ([link](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/productivity)) which reads:

> Questions about the ability to get work done in an efficient manner

So if your question is about your productivity at work your post will be on topic. If that is so, do include the mentioned tag along any other you feel necessary.

---

Worth to note that there was a https://productivity.stackexchange.com/ site proposed on Area 51. However, this site failed to graduate and the proposal was dismissed.